# A special strictly positive Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Given a metric space $X$, let $B(x,r)$ the open ball with center $x \in X$ and radius $r>0$. Fix also a Borel measure $\mu: \mathscr{B}(X) \to \mathbf{R}$ which is strictly positive, i.e.,
$$
\forall x \in X, \forall r>0,\,\,\mu(B(x,r))>0.
$$

> Is there a name for the measures $\mu$ such that
>   $$
> \forall x\in X,\,\,\lim_{r\to 0}\mu(B(x,r))=0?
> $$

I would say that it coincides with atomless measures, since
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\mu(B(x,r))=\mu(\{x\});
$$
is it correct?